# What is included in a 'Server-State' Backup, and is it enough?

Tags: windows, backup, backupexec

When using **Veritas Backup Exec** and selecting **System State** as a backup item, what exactly is backed up?  Veritas seems to refer you to Microsoft, and Microsoft tends to be equally vague about what this backup includes.

If I have a server running nothing except **Windows 2003** and **Microsoft SQL Server**, and was to lose the machine entirely, what would I recover if I restored from a system state backup?  Would the machine be usable?  Would it contain any non-OS data?

Does System-State include **Active Directory** settings (on a domain controller, what would be restored)?

**Also, please provide a verifiable reference (via URL)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this ServerFault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/17624/what-is-a-system-state-backup-for)

Comment: No problem. (also need at least 15 characters!)

Answer (score 0):

It will not contain Non-OS data, you would lose all SQL data. It's typically registry info. AD info if it is a DC, boot files, SYSVOL, IIS if it is running it and system files.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc785306%28WS.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

System State refers to SYSTEM's state i.e. operating system only. In your case it will not include SQL database files. you will have to take SQL data backup separately.

Depending on the recovery model chosen for SQL databases, you can pick/choose the DB files.

The following table lists the elements the OS backs up:

Element to be Backed up     Domain Controller   Non-Domain Controller 
Active Directory (NTDS)     Yes                     No 
System Volume (SYSVOL)   Yes                     No 
Boot files               Yes                    Yes 
Registry                   Yes                    Yes 
COM+ class registration db  Yes                    Yes

The OS will back up information about certificate services regardless of domain controller (DC) status.