# Restored Domain Controller does not display any information using dcdiag command

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-controller, active-directory

I am testing restoring a domain controller from system state backup to different hardware in a non production environment as a sanity check for our restoration procedure.

When i run the dcdiag command I get "blank info back" and all that is displayed are two lines as follows:
Domain Controller Diagnosis

Performing initial setup:

and then I am returned to the command prompt. Even when I do dcdiag /v i get the same result.

I have double checked the DNS settings and Active Directory works properly. All FSMO roles are being held by this restored Domain Controller. I am able to join test pc's to the domain without issue etc

Is this a common issue or is there something that I am missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why is this behavior happening, however in the following thread I have explained how to perform successful restore.
[What is a system state backup for?](https://serverfault.com/questions/17624/what-is-a-system-state-backup-for/247908#247908)