# VmWare image to HDD

Tags: windows-server-2003, virtualization, vmware-server, physical-environment

!Hello, I am virtualizing a Windows 2003 Server in VMWare Server 2.0.2. My goal is to take the virtualized HDD and make it a physical one so that i can boot a real server from it and run it outside of a virtualized environment. I know of this answer which shows how to do this clearly, my only issue is that they use vmare workstation and vmware server doesn't have the "Use physical drive" option when following these steps. Here's the link to that answer.

http://www.howtoforge.com/converting-a-vmware-image-to-a-physical-machine

So after you have possibly reviewed that 3rd party answer could anyone suggest another way of doing so while using VMWare Server 2.0.2? Thanks to Everyone!

Comment: VMware Server 2.0.2? *Why*? It went end of general availability in 2008!

Comment: Here's how:
http://serverfault.com/questions/17624/what-is-a-system-state-backup-for/247908#247908
See my answer in the post.

Comment: @MDMarra: I guess because this the only VMware product that is not a stand-alone hypervisor. Isn't it?

Comment: However I'd recommend to migrate to [VMware ESXi](http://www.vmware.com/products/vsphere-hypervisor/) or Microsoft Hyper-V (doesn't require stand-alone hypervisor).

Comment: @abatishchev - no, there are others. Player, Workstation, etc.

Comment: @MDMarra: I'm not familiar with Workstation but Player is not a server solution, just player, pure desktop. That's what I mean.

Comment: @abatishchev neither are meant for use on a server, but VMware Server hasn't been meant for use on a server since 2008 either. That was my point.

Comment: So any other VMware server visualization solutions not requiring stand-alone hypervisor? No. That's was my point. I used VMware Server for a long after 2008 by myself. But it's (almost) 2014 and you find a better solution easily. The same for running Windows Server 2003.

Answer (score 1):

Back up the server with the backup tool of your choice. Follow that tool's procedure for a restore to dissimilar hardware.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion to such a tool? Also if it were free it would be much appreciated

Comment: [Windows has NTBackup built in](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998799(v=exchg.65).aspx). [Google is your friend](https://www.google.com/#q=server+2003+backup+tool).

Comment: Thank You SOSOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO MUCH!!  I have not completed the backup yet but this seems to be very assuring!

Comment: although i must ask, will i have to have the installation disk to restore this "backup"? or can I just copy it to a usb and boot from it?

Comment: At some point you're going to have to do some research on your own. That point is now. Part of being a *professional* is reading and understanding documentation. It's a critical skill that will carry you far.