# What all does a system state restore point save the state of in Windows Server 2016?

Tags: logging, windows-server-2016, system-state

I'm fairly certain, all though not all together certain that it saves / restores the state of:

- The Registry
- Installed Software
- Server Settings (which I would assume generally get installed in the registry, unless they're `*.ini` files.)

But not:

- The Logs, as the logs should generally be sent somewhere else...like for instance a logging server...which are generally sent other places as well like a redundant logging server or two or three of them...

Comment: See the accepted answer here - https://serverfault.com/questions/17624/what-is-a-system-state-backup-for

Comment: @joeqwerty Thanks ,and sorry for the duplicate.  I see I even had that in my favorites.